# Questions on CSS and Styling

Tags: html, css

I want to add a second Pokemon Ball on the same line and make it on the far right side and I will remove the search function as its only Gen 1.

[image: One Pokemon Ball]

I have two Pokemon Balls now, here is the image:

[image: Two Pokemon Balls]

Here is my source code in HTML for the images:

> ````
>    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
>        <div class="floatLeft">
>        <img src="img/pokemon_logo.png" height="40%" width="50%" alt="Pokemon Logo" />
>      </div>
>
>      <h1><strong>Gen 1 Pokemon</strong></h1>
>
>      <div class="floatRight">
>        <img src="img/pokemon_logo2.png" height="40%" width="50%"  alt="Pokemon Logo"/>
>      </div>
>      <!-- <img src="img/pokemon_alt.png" height="20%" width="20% "alt="Pokemon Logo"> -->
>      </a>
>
>
>    <!-- This is where we can search for pokemon -->
>    <!-- <form class="form-inline">
>      <input class="form-control mr--2" id="search-pokemon" type="search" placeholder="Search for Pokemon" aria-label="Search">
>    </form> -->   </nav>```
> ````

This is what I have in CSS:

> ````
> .floatRight{ float:right; clear:right; margin-left:1400px; }```
> ````

I have tried align, float and all that cannot seem to figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Thanks everyone, I appreciate it a lot.... 

Just a dude trying to learn the zen of the code!

Answer (score 0):

try to not use floats, they are a bit "old" for todays standards.

For this purpose you can use Flexbox - more about it here:
[Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```
.navbar-brand {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to help!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the float right and float left styles and class from html.

set the style

```
  `a {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
   }`
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `display: flex;` and `justify-content: space-between;` to achieve this

```css
.content {
  margin: 50 auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to help!